# Rails controller not passing through value from Angular controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a friendship between 2 users and I'm using the [tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?autoplay=true)

I have this as my friendships_controller.rb,

```
def create
  @friendship = current_user.friendships.build(:friend_id => params[:friend_id])
  if @friendship.save
    flash[:notice] = "Added friend."
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    flash[:error] = "Unable to add friend."
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

And in Angular I have this function,

```
$scope.addFriend = function (user) {
  $scope.user = user
  console.log ($scope.user)

  createFriend.create({
    friend_id:   $scope.user.id
  })
}
```

And this is the create methode in my Angular service,

```
app.factory('createFriend', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    create: function() {
      return $http.post('/friendships.json');
    }
  };
}])
```

When I add a friend I get this in my rails console,

```
Started POST "/friendships.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-29 12:51:59 +0100
Processing by FriendshipsController#create as JSON
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (9.9ms)  INSERT INTO "friendships" ("user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2015-12-29 11:51:59.550777"], ["updated_at", "2015-12-29 11:51:59.550777"]]
   (17.6ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 39ms (ActiveRecord: 27.7ms)
```

As you can see from the console output the `friend_id` parameter is missing.

It's added in the database thought,

```
create_table "friendships", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "friend_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

When I run `Friendship.all` in my rails console I get,

```
<Friendship id: 1, user_id: 1, friend_id: nil, created_at: "2015-12-29 11:36:46", updated_at: "2015-12-29 11:36:46">
```

Any ideas why the `friend_id` parameter isn't being used?

Comment: can you please include the `createFriend.create` method code? or are you sure it's passing the params correctly?

Comment: @basia I've added the create method from my Angular service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass arguments from `createFriend.create` to `$http.post`. If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post), `$http.post` takes url as first argument and request content as second. Right now, `{friend_id:   $scope.user.id}` is simply being ignored. Something like  (not tested) code below should do the trick.

```
app.factory('createFriend', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    create: function(data) {
      return $http.post('/friendships.json', data);
    }
  };
}])
```

Comment: Thanks I missed that part. Small note, instead of `data` I can use `user`. Might make it a bit more readable. Thanks for the input.